# Git push to Assembla repository from multiple machines

Tags: git, push, assembla

I'm just getting to know git and I really can't find a documented solution to the following problem. Assembla.com allows only one public SSH key per user. The question is, is there a way to "push" from 2 different PCs? For example, creating a separate private/public key pair and sharing it between the 2 machines just for this use would help or that is not an advisable practice?

Answer (score 3):

Create private key on one machine. Copy it to the other, but use different name (like git_id_rsa). Then add id to your identity collection using `ssh-add path-to-git_id_rsa`. Then use `git push` as you would from the original machine.

Comment: You need to execute this prior to ssh-add: "eval ``ssh-agent``" in bash

Answer (score 1):

Assembla now allows multiple ssh keys (even for their free accounts).  You'll just need to add them here (start|profile| Manage Git Settings):

http://www.assembla.com/user/ssh_keys

nicely hidden below the page :)

Answer (score 0):

Create another SSH key for Assembla on the other PC as well. Name it something like: `assembla` and `assembla_rsa.pub` for differentiating them from the other keys that may be present.